# Drop rows if combination of multiple rows match regex value(s) using R dplyr (or other)

Tags: r, dplyr

First off, I'm not very well versed in R, I code mainly in Bash and sometimes in python. That being said, I have a dataframe with the following (variable) structure. Between the columns 'info' and 'gene' there can be upto 5 columns and may have different names. The data content in each column will start with either r,Ref,n,N,No_GT,Hom or het. If a column starts with Ref, No_GT, Hom or Het, it will have additional data delimited by :.

For ex. demo table below.

| info | s1 | gene |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | r | GG |
| b | Hom:10,10:20:99 | TG |
| c | Het:5,6:11:20 | TGGB |

To identify the column names of my interest, I'm using this snippet-

```
my_file %>% select('info':'gene') %>% colnames() -> samples
samples <- samples[! samples %in% c("info","gene")]
```

In case there is a single column, I need to remove rows containing r,n,N,Ref,No_GT. This can be achieved using grepl and a regex match. For ex. using

```
df[!grepl("^r|^n|^N|^Ref|^No_GT", df$s1),]
```

And the first row is removed.

However, there may be more columns between info and gene, example:

| info | s1 | s2 | gene |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | r | n | GG |
| b | Hom:10,10:20:99 | n | TG |
| c | Het:5,6:11:20 | r | TGGB |

My problem arises when there are multiple samples. In this case, I have to drop rows where all sample columns have combination of r,n,N,Ref and No_GT, i.e. if any of the sample has Hom or Het at the beginning, the row has to be preserved. I have the names of columns, but not entirely sure what the optimum way to solve this problem! I could cycle through each column, but then how do I break out if I encounter a Hom or Het?

Any help appreciated!

I tried using filter and select, however I'm not able to specify multiple columns even when using across.

I thought tried this -

```
my_file_sorted %>% filter(across(c(s1,s2), ~ "^Het|^Hom")) -> trimmed
```

However I'm getting this error

```
Error in `filter()`:
! Problem while computing `..1 = across(.cols = c(s1, s2))`.
✖ Input `..1$s1` must be a logical vector, not a character.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `if_any`:

```
df %>%
  filter(if_any(matches("^s[0-9]+$"), str_detect, pattern = "^(Hom|Het)"))
```

or `pmp_lgl`:

```
df %>%
  filter(
    pmap_lgl(
      select(., matches("^s[0-9]+$")), 
      ~any(str_detect(c(...), "^(Hom|Het)"))
    )
  )
```

If you know which columns are required for this test and have them in vector `my_cols` you just replace `matches("^s[0-9]+$")` with `all_of(my_cols)`

Comment: Hello, sorry to reply so late, but got sidetracked with other work. The ```if_any``` code snippet worked just fine!