# Group rows by a column, then keep only rows with alternating values in different specified

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, bioinformatics

From my [previous query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74384630/drop-rows-if-combination-of-multiple-rows-match-regex-values-using-r-dplyr-or), I have obtained the following data using R -

| info | s1 | s2 | s3 | gene |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | Het | Het | Ref | AA |
| b | Het | Ref | Het | AA |
| c | Het | Ref | Ref | AB |
| d | Het | Ref | Het | AB |
| e | Het | Ref | Het | AC |
| f | Het | Ref | Het | AC |
| g | Het | Het | Het | AD |
| h | Het | Het | Het | AD |
| i | Het | Het | Het | AZ |
| j | Het | Het | Het | AZ |
| k | Het | Ref | Het | AZ |
| l | Het | Het | No_GT | AZ |
| m | Het | Het | Ref | BC |
| n | Het | Het | Ref | BC |

The entries (which can be more than two entries) are grouped by gene. I want to retain all the info rows where s1 and s2 have `Het` values in alternating column, for example if in first row s2 has `Het` and s3 has `Ref` or `No_GT`, the second or any subsequent row should have s2 as `Ref` or `No_GT` and s3 as `Het`. Even if there are 20 rows, and the alternating `het` value is present in any two columns, all of them need to be retained

I would drop 'g' and 'h' as both s2 and s3 share the same value - `Het`. I would also drop 'm' and 'n', as only s2 column has `Het` value, i.e. no alternating `Het` in second column.

In the end, I would like to remain only with these entries -

| info | s1 | s2 | s3 | gene |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | Het | Het | Ref | AA |
| b | Het | Ref | Het | AA |
| c | Het | Ref | Ref | AB |
| d | Het | Ref | Het | AB |
| i | Het | Het | Het | AZ |
| j | Het | Het | Het | AZ |
| k | Het | Ref | Het | AZ |
| l | Het | Het | Ref | AZ |

Entries from AZ are retained, because there is at least one instance where two rows have alternating `Het` values.

I can group the rows by gene by retaining only duplicates in column `gene`, however I'm not sure how to describe the condition that I need, i.e. alternating values of Het in the columns s2 and s3. Any help or guidance would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

We will need `dplyr`.

```
library(dplyr)
```

First, I'll just copy your dataframe.

```
data <-
  tibble(
  info = letters[1:14],
  s1 = rep('Het', 14),
  s2 = c('Het', rep('Ref', 5), rep('Het', 4), 'Ref', rep('Het', 3)),
  s3 = c('Ref', 'Het', 'Ref', rep('Het', 8), 'No_GT', 'Ref', 'Ref'),
  gene = c(rep('AA', 2), rep('AB', 2), rep('AC', 2), rep('AD', 2), rep('AZ', 4), rep('BC', 2))
)
```

Then, we create a function that checks if two values are equal to 'Het' exclusively, that is, if one is 'Het', the other needs not to be, and at least one of them needs to be equal to 'Het'. Here, I'm assuming you also want to get rid of genes with no 'Het' present in `c(s1,s2,s3)` columns.

```
alternates_het <- function(current, previous){

  (current == 'Het') + (previous == 'Het') == 1

}
```

For each row, we apply this function to `s2` and the previous value of `s2`. Same for `s3`. In order to do so at the same time, we use `dplyr::across` inside `mutate`, creating two new columns.

```
data %>%
  group_by(gene) %>%
  mutate(across(c('s2', 's3'),
                .fns = list(alternate = ~alternates_het(., lag(.)))
                ))

# A tibble: 14 × 7
# Groups:   gene [6]
   info  s1    s2    s3    gene  s2_alternate s3_alternate
   <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <lgl>        <lgl>       
 1 a     Het   Het   Ref   AA    NA           NA          
 2 b     Het   Ref   Het   AA    TRUE         TRUE        
 3 c     Het   Ref   Ref   AB    NA           NA          
 4 d     Het   Ref   Het   AB    FALSE        TRUE        
 5 e     Het   Ref   Het   AC    NA           NA          
 6 f     Het   Ref   Het   AC    FALSE        FALSE       
 7 g     Het   Het   Het   AD    NA           NA          
 8 h     Het   Het   Het   AD    FALSE        FALSE       
 9 i     Het   Het   Het   AZ    NA           NA          
10 j     Het   Het   Het   AZ    FALSE        FALSE       
11 k     Het   Ref   Het   AZ    TRUE         FALSE       
12 l     Het   Het   No_GT AZ    TRUE         TRUE        
13 m     Het   Het   Ref   BC    NA           NA          
14 n     Het   Het   Ref   BC    FALSE        FALSE
```

As you can see, this yields `NA` for the first row of each group. I will assume for now that, if a group has only one row, you're considering that 'Het' does not alternate (regardless if it has 'Het' in any of the columns). With that in mind, we will for now replace `NA` by `FALSE` with another `mutate` + `across`.

```
data %>%
  group_by(gene) %>%
  mutate(across(c('s2', 's3'),
                .fns = list(alternate = ~alternates_het(., lag(.)))
                )) %>%
  mutate(across(where(is.logical), ~if_else(is.na(.), FALSE, (.))))
```

Now we filter off whichever group has no `TRUE`s in it, that is, if there is not a single row that alternates. The code is at last like this:

```
data %>%
  group_by(gene) %>%
  mutate(across(c('s2', 's3'),
                .fns = list(alternate = ~alternates_het(., lag(.)))
                )) %>%
  mutate(across(where(is.logical), ~if_else(is.na(.), FALSE, (.)))) %>%
  filter(if_any(where(is.logical), \(x) sum(x) > 0 )) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(all_of(names(data)))
```

This yields what you needed, if I understand correctly your question:

```
  info  s1    s2    s3    gene 
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 a     Het   Het   Ref   AA   
2 b     Het   Ref   Het   AA   
3 c     Het   Ref   Ref   AB   
4 d     Het   Ref   Het   AB   
5 i     Het   Het   Het   AZ   
6 j     Het   Het   Het   AZ   
7 k     Het   Ref   Het   AZ   
8 l     Het   Het   No_GT AZ
```

If you want groups of genes with a single row to be kept in the final data, just define the function inside the filter as `sum(x) > 0 | length(x) == 1`.